# Android 2.3 emulator blank screen after build

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I'm trying to build Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) from scratch on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine.

I've followed all the steps here:  http://source.android.com/source/building.html  Got no build errors.

But for some reason the emulator boots and the screen stays blank (I did try leaving it for a few hours even).  I built 2.2 a few months back on this same machine without issue.

Update:  As you can see from the image - adb detects the emulator briefly but when I run it again about 30 seconds later it does not detect it at all.

What could I have missed?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to run the emulator with the `logcat` parameter? Maybe it will show what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

According to a google employee in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-building/browse_thread/thread/58da9a6d14c37126), your building tools may be out of date.  Check out the link for more information, but his recommendation for building it is:

```
repo forall sdk external/qemu -c git checkout aosp/tools_r12
# build, possibly a clean build
emulator -kernel prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu-armv7
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your JDK version is 5, because you have built Froyo before. You should install JDK 6 to build Gingerbread.